# How to write input after executing bin using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm executing a bin file that gives a prompt for input. How do I write to that bin from within the shell script?

```
#! /bin/bash
./bin/file_name

for i in {1..5}
do
    echo "This is a command" #this is wrong....
done
```

Comment: If you have control over the *bin* program, change it so that it can be driven non-interactively. Then realize this is one of the first things you should have learned, and go back and change all your other programs.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the bin program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to interact with a program.

For simple tasks you can also pipe data to the program:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n" | ./bin/file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Most sane programs (I.e., doesn't try to listen for actual keyboard events) should accept standard input:

```
echo "some input" | ./bin/file_name
```